# How does this OpenGL Haskell code work?

Tags: opengl, haskell, monads

I'm learning Haskell by jumping straight into OpenGL and I can't seem to decipher this code:

```
display :: DisplayCallback
display = do
  let color3f r g b = color $ Color3 r g (b :: GLfloat)
      vertex3f x y z = vertex $ Vertex3 x y (z :: GLfloat)

  clear [ColorBuffer]
  renderPrimitive Quads $ do
    color3f 1 0 0
    vertex3f 0 0 0
    vertex3f 0 0.2 0
    vertex3f 0.2 0.2 0
    vertex3f 0.2 0 0

    color3f 0 1 0
    vertex3f 0 0 0
    vertex3f 0 (-0.2) 0
    vertex3f 0.2 (-0.2) 0
    vertex3f 0.2 0 0

    color3f 0 0 1
    vertex3f 0 0 0
    vertex3f 0 (-0.2) 0
    vertex3f (-0.2) (-0.2) 0
    vertex3f (-0.2) 0 0

    color3f 1 0 1
    vertex3f 0 0 0
    vertex3f 0 0.2 0
    vertex3f (-0.2) 0.2 0
    vertex3f (-0.2) 0 0
  flush
```

My understanding so far:

1. `display` is a function. **QUESTION:** What is DisplayCallback?
2. `do` indicates chaining of computations, something to do with IO monads
3. `color3f` and `vertex3f` are local functions with three arguments defined within `do` using the `let` keyword
4. I assume that `color` and `vertex` is an openGL wrapper function for `glColor*` and `glVertex*`.

Now this is where it gets confusing:

- `Color3` and `Vertex3` appears to be some sort of data structure consisting of three arguments. **QUESTION:** Why is it necessary to use a data structure here? Why the designers of the API chose to use it here?
- `color3f` function calls `color` function and passes in single argument - data structure `Color3` with data r g b. For some reason data type here is specified for only the last argument `(b :: GLfloat)` **QUESTION:** Why is the data type specified only for the last argument, why is it specified here at all?
- **QUESTION:** Why is the dollar sign used when calling the `color` function `color $ Color3 r g (b :: GLfloat)`?

Continuing on:

1. `clear` is wrapper for opengl `glClear` and takes as an argument a list, in this case containing only a single element `[ColorBuffer]`.
2. `renderPrimitive` appears to be wrapper function for opengl `glBegin`, `Quads` appears to be datatype. **QUESTION:** What happens next? What does `$ do` indicate? (series of computations? *something, something* IO monads?).
3. `flush` is wrapper for `glFlush`.

Comment: (Learning by using a binding to a large external library is likely to distort your picture of Haskell, as your experience will be skewed by the decisions made by (a) the decisions, including language choice, of the OpenGL authors and (b) the decisions, including imperative to functional translation, of the Haskell binding authors. In particular, these huge blocks of monadic code smell of imperative, and I would go to some lengths when writing Haskell code to avoid that. Sadly, some external libraries do tend to push you in this unidiomatic direction.)

Comment: I jumped in straight with OpenGL(which i'm familiar with), because computer graphics and gamedev is exactly what I'm gonna use Haskell for. I'll try to stick to idiomatic Haskell and pure functional programming whenever possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 . `DisplayCallback` is a type synonym for `IO ()`. You can use hoogle to look things up, or type `:i DisplayCallback` in ghci.

The reason that `IO ()` is given a special name is because `GLUT` is based on callbacks: functions are registered to handle a specific event, such as displaying, input events, resize events, etc. For the full list, see the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLUT-2.5.1.0). You don't need the type synonyms, obviously, but they are provided for clarity and better communication.

2 . "I assume that color and vertex is an openGL wrapper function for glColor* and glVertex*." Not quite - `OpenGL` is a wrapper around the more basic `OpenGLRaw`, which is a 1:1 mapping of the c opengl library to haskell. `vertex` and `color` are slightly more sophisticated that `glColor` and `glVertex`, but you can probably assume for most uses they are the same.

More specifically, `vertex` is a member of the `Vertex` class which has 4 instances `Vertex4`, `Vertex3`, and `Vertex2`.

3 . `Color3` is defined as `data Color3 a = Color3 !a !a !a`. [The exclamation indicates that the fields are strict.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Data_types). Why is this necessary? Well, they could have easily used `(a,a,a) -> IO ()` or `a -> a -> a -> IO ()` but then a function taking a color is indistinguishable from one taking a vector, which are "ideologically" different objects, even if they are represented by precisely the same data (Vertex is `data Vertex3 a = Vertex3 !a !a !a`). So you don't want to be able to pass a vertex to a function requiring a color. Also, these datatypes give better performance, ideally, due to the strictness.

4 . Why is the type specified at all? Short answer, is the type system requires it. The type of a literal is `Num a => a` which is too polymorphic for the datatype, which requires a concrete type. So you pick said concrete type by using a type annotation.

Why is it only required in one place? The compiler can infer the type of the other fields. Look back to the data type decleration - all three fields must have the same type. If one field is annotated, the rest are trivially inferred. You can also write `Color3 r (g :: GLfloat) b` or `Color3 (r :: GLfloat) g b` or give the function `vertex3f` a type signature.

5 . The `$` is just function application with low precedence, it is defined as `f $ a = f a; infixr $ 0`. You can also write `color (Color3 r g (b :: GLfloat))` so it is purely a matter of style here.

6 . [Perhaps the docs will again best explain what `renderPrimitive` is doing.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-2.9.1.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-GL-BeginEnd.html#v:renderPrimitive) But the short version is this: instead of writing things inside of a `glBegin` - `glEnd` block, you write it inside of `renderPrimitive`. You don't need to write `glEnd` because this is hidden inside of `renderPrimitive`. So your code is equivalent to:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS); 
// All the stuff inside goes here ...
glEnd ();
```

The `OpenGL` does some magic in order to bring exceptions from c into the haskell universe properly, but you don't really have to worry about that.

Final comment: If you plan to use haskell for graphics, the writing actual openGL code is probably not the best idea. After all, if you are going to use openGL, why not just use c? There are a whole myriad of graphics libraries out there. You should browse hackage for a package that is right for you. I'm afraid I can't recommend anything as I'm not familiar with what packages are available.

Comment: Thank you. Actual OpenGL code usually ends up being only a smart portion of the overall solution. Haskell appears to be terse and expressive which is exactly what I'm looking for. It appears to be worth learning and exploring.

Comment: Regarding the 5., why can't i specify type constraints by writing: color3f (r :: GLfloat) g b = color $ Color3 r g b ?

Comment: I also tried specifying type constraints using color3f :: (GLfloat a) => a -> a -> a -> IO (), which doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: @JBeurer Try adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of the program, and then `color3f (r :: GLFloat) g b = ...` should work. By default, you can't put a type signature in a pattern. Not because it's bad, just because nobody thought of it.

Comment: Also, `GLFloat` is not a type class, it is a type. So you would write `GLfloat -> GLfloat -> GLfloat -> IO ()`. `GLfloat` is in fact isomorphic to `Float`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the actual library in question, but I think I can answer a few of your points.

I would expect that `DisplayCallback` is merely an alias to some more complicated type signature. If you open up GHCi and import the necessary modules, you should be able to say

```
:i DisplayCallback
```

and it'll tell you what it refers to. Then at least you'll see the definition, even if that doesn't necessarily tell you what it's *for*.

The `do` notation isn't just for the IO monad, it's for *any monad*. I wouldn't be surprised if OpenGL drawing operations happen in their own specialised monad.

Why is `GLFloat` specified? I imagine that `Color3` and `Vector3` are defined to hold *any type* of ordinate. We want it to be `GLFloat`, hence the type signature. Why is it only on *one* of the coordinates? I would imagine that the definition of `Color3` requires *all* ordinates to have the same type, so specifying it for one automatically causes the other two to have the same type.

Why does `Color3` even exist at all? Why can't we just call `color` with three inputs? Well, that's an API design choice, but again I wouldn't be surprised if the definition of `Color3` and `Vector3` allows you to do arithmetic on entire vectors or colors. So by putting coordinates into a vector, you get to treat them as a single unit, do arithmetic on them, easily store them in lists, etc. If you're doing all that, you don't really want to have to unpack them all again in order to actually call OpenGL functions.

What is the dollar sign for? Well, if I write

```
color Color3 r g b
```

this means that I'm calling `color`, passing it four arguments: `Color3`, `r`, `g` and `b`. That isn't what we want. What we want is

```
color (Color3 r g b)
```

That is, calling `color` with *one* argument. You can do that using brackets, or you can use `$` instead. It's a bit like the Unix pipe, in that it lets you turn

```
func3 (func2 (func1 x))
```

into

```
func3 $ func2 $ func1 $ x
```

If you have a *lot* of functions, it can be annoying to get the right number of closing brackets. For just one function call, it's a matter of taste.

The `renderPrimitive` function is taking *two* arguments. One of them is `Quads` (whatever that is), and the other is *the entire do-block*. So you're passing all of that code as an argument to the `renderPrimitive` function (which presumably executes it somehow).

Hopefully this gives you some enlightenment.